# IE window.open on second session opens a window with first session id

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, sessionid

I have an *asp.net* application and I need to have two sessions running at once.

I also use `windows.open` on some of my pages, and this is where my problem starts. If I have two sessions running when I call `windows.open` in JavaScript from one of my pages in session two, the new window opens with the session id from session one.

I should also add that the second session is created in a different IE instance using the code below.

```
var myshell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");

if (parseFloat(ieVersion) >= 8) {
    myshell.ShellExecute("iexplore.exe", "-noframemerging " + url, "", "open", 1);
}
else {
    myshell.ShellExecute("iexplore.exe", url, "", "open", 1);
}
```

Comment: same problem can be found here giving example

http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/session-id-getting-changed-opening-new-window-window-open-ie-internet-explorer-t664397.html

Comment: Do you control the server or not ? What I mean here is if you can change something on web site then you can have two sessions at ones, but if you can not control the server and the web site, then it will be tricky

Comment: Yes I am able to access the server settings, please advise if there is a setting I can change to allow two sessions at once.

Comment: Is this an IIS setting or GPO setting? @Aristos Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Aristos Do you know what I need to change on the server to allow two sessions at once?

Comment: I am not so sure, I am little confuse with this that why I do not answer. Look at this parameters and try to see if this can work. On web.config the `httpCookies` the domain, and the name of the cookie. The cookie can be diferent if you ask for www.domain.com and www1.domain.com  So with changing the front www you can have two different cookies at the same site... but you need to make some test to find the right way.

Comment: Eg if you call from the one the www.domain.com and from the other www1.domain.com, and set correct settings on httpcookies (probably you need to set domain="www.domain.com" on your web.config, you can have different cookies.

Comment: One test that you can do. on web.config on httpcookies, you set domain=www.domain.com, then you open your first page ag www.domain.com and the second on domain.com, and maybe this simple works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have know idea why this is but I found the problem...

The new window opened from the second instance of IE was not loading correctly and was rendering back on the first instance of IE.

The javascript to open the window is simply:
window.open(the_url, "DisplayWindow", option);

This works on the first instance of IE just fine, and on some computers running Windows 7 and IE 9 it works opening a window on the second instance of IE, but for other computers running the same set up this just dosnt work!

**The solution is simply to remove the window name.

window.open(the_url, "", option);**

I also found a similar issue where in IE9 the window will not open if the window name contains a space! So try changing the window name or removing it if you have a similar problem.